# Undefined Control Sequence Error in PDFLatex with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I receive two errors when using `\includegraphics` command in pdflatex. I've never seen these particular errors discussed/answered before.

I have the following MWE (this is all I have in the document so far):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.92]{box.png}
\hspace{0.5in}\parbox{6in}{\caption{Box comparing two methods \label{box}}} 
\end{center} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where box is the figure to be included. There are two errors produced. Both of them say the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

recently read \ltx@zapspace
```

I do not know what these errors mean. I assume they have something to do with `\ltx@zapspace`. I appreciate any help or clarification of this error or how to correct it.

Comment: `\ltx@zapspace` is defined by the `ltxcmds` package. You could load that. However, your example compiles for me (with another image).

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I have separately included \usepackage(ltxcmds}, but the same errors result. Is there some manual correction that needs to be made here?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz There is no need to load additional packages, because `pdftex.def` already contains `\RequirePackage[2010/12/07]`. This is not accidentally the version that introduces `\ltx@zapspace`.

Answer (score 5):

Driver file `pdftex.def` uses package `ltxcmds` since version `2011/04/21 v0.06`:

```
 \RequirePackage{ltxcmds}[2010/12/07]
```

Macro `\ltx@zapspace` is provided by package `ltxcmds` since this version `2010/12/07 v1.14`.

Thus very likely an outdated package is the cause and LaTeX throws a warning, e.g.:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 408, version
               `2010/12/07' of package ltxcmds,
               but only version
               `2009/08/05 v1.0 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)'
               is available.
```

Solution: update at least package `ltxcmds`, better the whole bundle `oberdiek`.

Comment: Heiko, you are correct. I see that message (only with different dates): LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 406, version `2010/12/07' of package ltxcmds, but only version
`2010/04/26 v1.7 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)'
is available. Can you please clarify how to update either the ltxcmds or oberdiek packages? I'm a novice to latex and not sure how to do this.